# ingress-nginx helm chart upgrade failed 'could not get information about the resource ValidatingWebhookConfiguration'

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, helm

I'm trying to upgrade my `ingress-nginx` helm chart from `v4.8.3` to `v4.8.4` with this command:

```shell
    helm upgrade \
        --reuse-values \
        --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.networkPolicy.enabled=false \
        --version 4.8.4 \
        --namespace ingress-nginx \
        ingress-nginx \
        ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

NB. I set the `controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.networkPolicy.enabled` field since it is now required in the [networkpolicy.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/commit/bfc2300c3d0cd35aa16324b35d865b7a0a6f4bbb) file.

And I got this error:

```shell
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: Unable to continue with update: could not get information about the resource ValidatingWebhookConfiguration "ingress-nginx-%!s(<nil>)" in namespace "": invalid resource name "ingress-nginx-%!s(<nil>)": [may not contain '%']
```

Any clue on what could go wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is no more relevant: `v4.8.4` has been removed from releases.

As explained in this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/10784#issuecomment-1864776862), the release was a mistake. It had incompatible changes with the controller and was not a patch release.

By the way the reported [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/10733) is closed. It is advised to downgrade to `v4.8.3`.

[UPDATE]

I keep getting the same error while upgrading from `v4.8.3` to `v4.9.1`. But at least I found a workaround by getting rid of the `--reuse-values` flag and re-setting the previous values with the `--set` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error presented, the issue might be lying with the naming of the ValidatingWebhookConfiguration resource during the upgrade. Name format could be incorrect and causing the issue. Make sure the format is correct in your Helm chart such as special characters and placeholders. Double check the version as well to make sure it's compatible with the chart. You may also try to uninstall/reinstall the Helm release as it may also be a factor.

‘helm uninstall ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx’

‘helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx’

Hope these suggestions help you in troubleshooting your use case.